# why is my image being drawn incorrectly in Microsoft paint?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a program that's goal is to re-draw pictures in Microsoft paint, however, instead of recreating the exact image, it places every pixel in the wrong place. for example, here is an image I would try to [recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb2NT.jpg) and here is the image it would [draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtZSB.png)
here is my (python)code:

```
import pyautogui as py
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import time
from playsound import playsound

im = Image.open('google.jpg')  # Can be many different formats.
pix = im.load()

a = 0
b = 0
c = 460
d = 0
e = 0
g = 0
x, y = 5, 144
pixx, pixy = 0, 0
w, h = im.size

py.moveTo(x=132, y=1080)
time.sleep(1)
py.click()
while a <= w * h:
    py.click(x=984, y=95)
    while b <= 2:
        py.doubleClick(x=831, y=c)
        f = str(pix[pixx, pixy][b])
        py.write(f)
        b += 1
        c += 20
    py.click(x=466, y=520)
    b = 0
    c = 460
    d += 1
    a += 1
    if pixx < w:
        pixx += 1
    if pixx == w:
        pixx = 0
        pixy += 1
    if e < w and g <= h:
        py.click(x, y)
        x += 1
        e += 1
        # pixx += 1
    elif e == w and g <= h:
        py.click(x, y)
        g += 1
        y += 1
        x = 5
        e = 0
        # pixx = 0
        # pixy += 1
    else:
        playsound('bruh.mp3')
        print('bruh')

playsound('bruh.mp3')
```

Comment: Apparently you are calculating the x and y coordinates incorrectly.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems in your code, both of which stem from the fact that your code isn't DRY.

DRY stands for Don't Repeat Yourself. Your code has separate code for selecting the next pixel from the source image, and where to paint the pixel in the destination image. The behaviour of these two things needs to be identical, but because it uses different code paths, it becomes likely that a mistake somewhere will make this behaviour different.

It's impossible for me to test your code locally, but I think the two mistakes are:

- the source pixel is read *before* the source pixel coordinates are updated, but the destination pixel is clicked *after* the destination pixel coordinates are updated
- the source pixel is checked if it's beyond the end of the line after its x coordinate is updated - the destination pixel is checked if it's beyond the end of the line only if it doesn't update the x coordinate (in the former case, there's an `if` instead of an `elif`)

Rather than looping for the correct number of pixels, why not loop over `x` and `y` separately, and then you can lose all the error-prone code where you check which coordinate you need to update.

Rather than updating two sets of coordinates, why not have one set, and a simple way to translate to the other set?

Something like:

```
def set_colour_from_source(x, y):
    py.click(x=984, y=95)
    for b in range(2):
        c = 460 + (20 * b)
        py.doubleClick(x=831, y=c)
        f = str(pix[x, y][b])
        py.write(f)
    py.click(x=466, y=520)

def get_destination_coords(x, y):
    return (5 + x, 144 + y)

for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        set_colour_from_source(x, y)
        dx, dy = get_destination_coords(x, y)
        py.click(dx, dy)
```

Comment: I tried it but, it only moves the mouse to the top left corner of the screen?

Comment: I've not included everything from your original code; only bits to demonstrate how to approach the problem differently - I didn't include, for example, your initial `moveTo`

Comment: I also had a bug where I passed the wrong coordinates to `py.click` :blush: